# Play fullscreen video from a link on iOS Safari

Tags: ios, html, html5-video, mobile-safari

I want to play an .mp4 video with the fullscreen player in a iPhone when the user clicks a link, for example:

```html
<a href="http://www.example.com/video.mp4">Play the video</a>
```

When the video finishes, I want to hide the fullscreen video and show the user the webpage again, without showing the paused / finished video area to the user. Is there any way to do it?

I already tried the HTML5 `<video>` element (shows the video area when I exit the fullscreen mode) and a direct link (must hit back in the browser to return the webpage). Any ideas?

Comment: Why specifically iOS and Safari?

Comment: If there is an universal solution to made it work this way in any mobile device it will be great, but I need to made it work this way at least in iOS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that using HTML5 `<video>` is definitely the way to go, but using some tweaks..

Start with adding a link and a `video` object. We'll make the video hidden so it won't show the preview thumbnail. The link will call a JavaScript function:

```
<a href="javascript:playVideo();">Play the video</a>
<video id="video-player" style="display:none !important;">
    <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

The JavaScript part will trigger the play on the `video` object and will also add a handler to the "video ended" event so we can automatically close the video when it ends:

```
function playVideo() {
  var videoPlayer = document.getElementById('video-player');
  videoPlayer.addEventListener('ended', onVideoEnded, false);
  videoPlayer.play();
}

function onVideoEnded(event) {
  var videoPlayer = document.getElementById('video-player');
  videoPlayer.webkitExitFullscreen();
}
```

Comment: This worked very well, just added "videoPlayer.webkitEnterFullscreen();" to make it compatible whit iPad. Also working well on chrome for android, silk for kindle fire and internet explorer for windows phone.

Comment: Cool! I only tested with iOS, but nice to know it also works on other platforms/browsers.